# Rotation with XMMatrix to Rotation with XMFLOAT3

Tags: rotation, directx11, lighting

I'm rotating a Direction Light around a fixed object, so the light only contains a XMFLOAT3 to determine it's direction that it is facing.

I have another object rotation using the variable Rotation which is an XMMATRIX.

```
Rotation = XMMatrixRotationAxis( rotaxis, rot);
```

I picked out the parts I needed by doing the following:

```
XMFLOAT3 newRotation;
newRotation.x = Rotation._11;
newRotation.y = Rotation._12;
newRotation.z = Rotation._13;
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this? An easier built in function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something as simple as [XMVector3TransformNormal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.transformation.xmvector3transformnormal%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the direction light with the original Rotation.

Generally in SIMD-friendly coding, individual component access is a performance hit, so you want to avoid doing it whenever possible. That's why in [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx) (aka XNAMath version 3) the individual element members _11 - _44 were removed from XMMATRIX. If you need to do individual matrix element access, you'd use XMStoreFloat4x4, XMStoreFloat4x3, XMStoreFloat3x3 and then extract the value from the non-SIMD structures XMFLOAT4X4 / XMFLOAT4X3 / XMFLOAT3X3.